# Filter collection by qty

Tags: magento, collections, filter

I try to filter a collection by quantity with:
`$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 30));`
but that doesn't work.

Can somebody give me a hint, to filter a product collection by quantity?

I also tried:

```
$stockCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getCollection()
                             ->addFieldToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 99999999));
$entityIds = array();
foreach ($stockCollection as $item) {
    $entityIds[] = $item->getOrigData('product_id');
}

$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('id', array('in' => $entityIds));
```

The entityId array is empty, but the $_productCollection still returns products?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Explanation:

You were close on your second attempt.  There's a special method for adding a qty filter in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock_Item_Collection`

```
/**
 * Add filter by quantity to collection
 *
 * @param string $comparsionMethod
 * @param float $qty
 * @return Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock_Item_Collection
 */
public function addQtyFilter($comparsionMethod, $qty)
{
    $methods = array(
        '<'  => 'lt',
        '>'  => 'gt',
        '='  => 'eq',
        '<=' => 'lteq',
        '>=' => 'gteq',
        '<>' => 'neq'
    );
    if (!isset($methods[$comparsionMethod])) {
        Mage::throwException(
            Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('%s is not a correct comparsion method.', $comparsionMethod)
        );
    }

    return $this->addFieldToFilter('main_table.qty', array($methods[$comparsionMethod] => $qty));
}
```

## Solution:

```
$stockIds = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addQtyFilter('>=', 30)
    ->getAllIds();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addIdFilter($stockIds)
    ->setPageSize(10);
```